# How to Sign Out from Firebase Auth?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Mine is coded in switch-case into a bottom navigation view bar. There is no error but it could not logout. Is there any typo?

The author did not give the source code, so I just coded like the previous session he gave. When I had register, the app could not let me logout, like directing me back to the main activity. Others recommended me to FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut() but is still not able to logout.

The flow of this code is Home -- Logout -- Main Activity. Is it necessary to set **private FirebaseAuth mAuth** at the top of the code ?? Or is it my Samsung phone?

```
package com.example.example.Seller;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.example.Buyer.MainActivity;
import com.example.example.R;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


public class SellerHome extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mTextMessage;

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            switch      (item.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);
                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_add:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_add_items);
                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_logout:
final FirebaseAuth mAuth;
                mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                mAuth.signOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(SellerHome.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                    return true;



            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_seller_home);
    }

}
```

[Does BottomNavigationView can affect the function of Firebase Auth?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJxxM.png)

Comment: Please explain more properly what you mean it could not logout

Comment: What are you expecting to see? `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()` should work fine. To test-run this, try to read a locked/protected firestore/storage value after signout, you'll get an error.

Comment: @TaslimOseni it's quite big step instead he can just check if user is logged in or no.

Comment: Can sellers access this SellerHome activity even when they are not authenticated?

Comment: What do you mean by "it could not log out"?

Comment: When user had register, they will reach to the main activity; however, when they go out, they could not exit.

Comment: The coding is ok but in the logcat, It come out just                             V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = null
D/ViewRootImpl@eb250ac[SellerHome]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@eb250ac[SellerHome]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are interested to hear the answer/solve story, I retype the whole thing which defines my BottomNavigationView. Somehow readjust the onCreate to the top.

Thanks for sharing the answer.

```
 package com.example.example.Seller;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.example.Buyer.MainActivity;
import com.example.example.R;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class SellerHome extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView mTextMessage;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_seller_home);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.seller_nav_view);



    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);
                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_add:

                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_add_items);
                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_logout:


                    final FirebaseAuth mAuth;
                    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                    mAuth.signOut();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SellerHome.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;

        }
    });




}
}
```